# ZF2 + DoctrineORMModule + Boolean field

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I'm setting up a form through annotations using

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", nullable=false, name="is_public")
 * @Annotation\Required(false)
 * @Annotation\AllowEmpty()
 * @Annotation\Attributes({"placeholder":"Is Public"})
 * @Annotation\Filter({"name":"boolean"})
 * @Annotation\Options({"label":"Is Public"})
 */
private $isPublic;
```

This form is built using the doctrine annotation builder and the doctrine entity hydrator. The entity is then bound to this form. There is an issue when passing a boolean field, in that any value is treated as false, except 1, passing 0 results in an error message of "cannot be empty".

Can somebody please advise as to how I can use boolean fields properly using this method? Ideally I'd like to be able to use the filter before the field is validated? Not only that, but the validation is ignoring the AllowEmpty() and Required(false) fields.

Kind Regards,

ise

Answer (score 0):

What you say is happening seems correct. Checkbox on forms submit nothing when unchecked, but the hydrator obviously needs to be able to know when the user intends to clear the value (mark false).

Pretty sure hydrator should work with empty string for false too. Required and AllowEmpty don't really make sense with a Boolean, especially in your case, because you also put nullable=false

Comment: Hi yes, the input is coming via rest json, and is definately available in the post data. This field is not a checkbox, I was adding in Required and AllowEmpty in the hope of bypassing the validator. Basically I have no way of being able to set this as false and pass the validator. I'm having to set nullable=true and treating any value other than 1 from the db as false. If I set the type to be checkbox, shud this start it working?

Answer (score 0):

This way I solved it $form->getInputFilter()->get('isPublic')->setContinueIfEmpty(true); just before $form->isValid()